# Navbar modification

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x library -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original code -->
<header class="header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

      <div class="login">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Using this code , while I am trying to run it and make the srceen smaller, login button is apparing in the middle:
[image]

But I want to align it in right , beside burger menu:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add `ms-auto` as class to the login. That will move the login to the right as `margin: auto` consumes all remaining space within flexbox. Note that you should also add a margin-right (`me-{size}`) to the same element or it will attach directly to the menu button:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x library -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original code -->
<header class="header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

      <div class="login ms-auto me-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Why does this have a -1? It's a correct answer

Answer (score -1):

You can put `login` & the `collapse button` into a parent tag like `section.log-but` and then set the display of the parent into `flex` and apply `justify-content: end;`.

```css
.log-but {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x library -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original code -->
<header class="header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <section class='log-but'>
      <div class="login">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          </section>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: dont overwrite Bootstrap if you can simply solve this with pure Bootstrap. Questions marked with Bootstrap should always be answered with a Bootstrap solution.

Comment: PS: There is also no need to wrap those elements into another element. Overwriting Bootstrap could be done with: `login { margin-left: auto; }` which will move the login to the right as `margin: auto` wiwll consume all remaining space. However The Bootstrap solution to add this is: `ms-auto` -> `margin start - auto`